# Coding model developed in Proc PHREG

Tags: sas, cox-regression

I have developed a COX model using SAS proc phreg procedure. I know how to score using the covariate using the proc procedure. How do I translate the model to simple sas code?

thanks.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you "translate" anything without seeing what they are to translate? You need to at least provide what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, someone gave me a solution. It was to use store statement in PHREG and then read the stored item in Proc PML and use code statement to export the model as SAS code. A bit convoluted, but it works.